# Current heap getting updated in java

Tags: java

I am writing a class for a heap in java.

The class heap has

```
 class Heap{
     int maxsize=1000;
     int[] heap= new int[maxsize];
     int size=0;
     //.... some methods basically, print, insert and remove

     int[] sortHeap (){
         int[] sorted= new int[size];
         Heap copy= new Heap();
         copy.heap=heap;
         copy.size=size;
         int i=0;
         while (copy.size>0){
             sorted[i]=copy.remove();
             i++;
         }
         return sorted;
     }
 }
```

One method I am trying to create is returning the sorted heap. I do not want to destroy the original heap.
However when I call this method, the original heap from which I am calling it gets destroyed.
Can some one explain to me why does this happen?

eg.
Say heap is
-17,
-1,  -7,
1,  0,  2,  -5,
17,  57,  27,  3,  127,  9,  // correctly printed

Now I call test.heapSort(); and then print the resultant array.

Then printing the heap after this gives the result

127,
127,  127,
57,  57,  127,  27,
27,  57,  27,  3,  127,  9,

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
copy.heap=heap;
```

does not copy the array. It just assigns the reference to the array `heap` to `copy.heap`. So both fields: `heap` and `copy.heap` point to the same array.

The correct way to copy the array's contents is:

```
System.arraycopy(heap, 0, copy.heap, 0, heap.length);
```